# Use "justify" for text alignment in MIT app inventor

Tags: text-alignment, app-inventor, justify

How to align text with "justify" alignment in MIT App Inventor?

Answer (score 0):

You can justify the Text  to Left  Center  Right  in a Label by setting the TextAlignment property of the Label (0 for Left, 1 for Center, 2 for Right justification).